# Add word Listing in front of number in list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I have to add the word `Listing` or `Lst.` in front of the number of a listings in the list-of-listings. I use the `listings` package. I know how to achieve this with tables:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Tab. 10\quad}
```

but is there something similar for the listings?

My current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\section{Test}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=TestListing]
test()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1em}{Listing #1}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\section{Test}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=TestListing]
test()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You were one minute faster. I was just typing the same answer, but was still wording some explanation text. :-) One suggestion: I would use `{\lstlistingname\space#1}` instead of `{Listing #1}` to keep it in sync if the listings name is ever changed, e.g. by `babel`.