# LaTeX List of listings name in front of number

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

I am having problems  with LaTeX specifically using `listings` package.

The first one is I want to add the word "Código" in front of number of Listing in List of Listings. For example

> **List of Listings**
>
> Código 1. function1.m ........... page 1
>
> Código 2. Function2.m ........... page 2

And the second one is: If I use  the option "title"  in `\lstset`, these titles do not appear in the List of Listings but it do appear at the top of  each listing. How  can I make titles appear in the List of Listings?

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) (and perhaps explain why [Add word Listing in front of number in list of listings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22502/5764) does not help)?

Comment: You can find another solution in this thread: [lstlistoflistings isn't showing the lstlistingname](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126654/27635)

Comment: Sorry, I had not found that solution. Thanks @karlkoeller!!

Comment: @user44179 You're welcome.